# How to make footer stick to bottom of wrapper with bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, margin, footer, sticky-footer

I´m trying to make a footer that sticks to the bottom of wrapper, but leaving a bottom margin so that the pattern image on the body background can be seen.
I came accross the sticky footer at

http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

which worked great, but all my attempts of adding margin/paddings to footer/ wrapper/ body didn´t.

I guess it must be a pretty simple thing, but I´m not finding it. Thanks for any hints/ suggestions!

Here´s the relevant CSS:

```
* 
{
    margin: 0;
}
html, body 
{
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url(images/modulo-pattern-grey-light.gif);
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper 
{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -98px;
    background: #fff url(images/footer.gif) left bottom no-repeat;
    width: 980px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px #999;
}
.footer, .push 
{
    height: 98px;
}

.footer 
{
    margin-left: 490px;
    margin-right: 40px; 
    background-color: #bc4c9b;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wraper">
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="logo">
</div>
<div class="menu_container">
<div class="main_menu">  
<ul>  
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>  
<li><a class="selected" >Quiénes Somos</a></li>  
<li><a href="consultoria.html">Consultoría</a></li>  
<li><a href="capacitacion.html">Capacitación</a></li>  
<li><a href="academico.html">Académico / Artículos</a></li>  
<li><a href="alianzas.html">Alianzas</a></li> 
<li><a href="proyectos.html">Proyectos</a></li>  
<li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>   
</ul>  
</div> 
</div>
<div class="quienes_pic"></div>
<div class="quienes_text"></div>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Sorry I didn´t mention, but Fixed position won´t work, since I want the same footer to work on different pages with differents heighs. The idea was to have the same wraper and footer through all the pages, and then assigning different body ids to set the different heighs

Pretty much like is done through this site:

http://www.casadelviento.com.ar/

In this case, it´s using different body ids AND different wrappers, I thought may be it could be done with less code and more clear (i.e I don´t understand why is the difference between the wraper heigh `#contenido-index` and the body heigh)

```
#contenido-index {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 2040px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-chicos {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 2760px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-adultos {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 2810px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-somos {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 2150px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-historia {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 980px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-horarios {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 967px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-contacto {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 750px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-videos {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 820px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#contenido-fotos {
background-color: #FFF;
height: 595px;
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#body-index {
height: 2160px;
}
#body-somos {
height: 2070px;
}
#body-historia {
height: 1150px;
}
#body-horarios {
height: 1060px;
}
#body-chicos {
height: 2700px;
}
#body-adultos {
height: 2800px;
}
#body-videos {
height: 960px;
}
#body-fotos {
height: 740px;
}
#body-contacto {
height: 880px;
}
/*FOOTER}*/
#contenedor_pie {
height: 40px;
width: 500px;
float: left;
margin-left: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: please show your basic HTML structure also :)

Comment: please try to put your code at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2):

With Reference to http://alt-web.com/DEMOS/CSS2-Sticky-Footer.shtml

You can define your footer HTML as

```
   <div id="Sticky">
       <h2>Here is a Sticky Footer</h2>
       <p>Test for Sticky Footer</p>
   </div>
```

then your CSS would be like

```
   #Sticky 
   {
       color:#FFF;
       text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333; 
       border: 2px solid orange;
       position:fixed;
       padding: 0 10px 0 10px;                 
       left: 0px;
       bottom: 0px;
       width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The reference demo is a cool footer option. Unfortunately I forgot to specify that I have different pages with different heighs, and I want the footer to be at the bottom of all of them, leaving the same margin-bottom, so I guess position should be relative to the wraper. I added further information on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do easily just define in your css some code as like this

***Css***

```
body{background:green;}
#wrapper {
background:red;
    min-height:700px;
}
.footer {
position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">Wraper text </div>

<div class="footer">Sticky footer</div>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/6z6Uk/
    ​

and now adjust according to your design .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and demo. I guess position should be relative to the wraper, since I have different pages with different heighs, and I want the footer to be at the bottom of all of them, leaving the same margin-bottom. I added further information on the post.